# How to iterate through very large text files and merge lines only when a certain condition exists

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

The underlying purpose is for me to become a python expert (long run) and the immediate goal is as follows...

I want to merge two massive lists into one. The lists are very large text files comprised of millions of lines which would look like the following-

```
         bigfile1                        bigfile2           
 (10,'red','blue','orange')         (10,'31','false','true')                         
 (11,'black','blue','green')        (11,'88','true','true')
 (12,'blue','blue','green')         random junk once in a while
 (13,'red','blue','yellow')         (12,'3','false','false')
 (14,'brown','red','red')           (15,'6','true','true')
```

Using Python, I would like to:

1. merge the lines from each list and write them to a new list if the       "usernumbers" before the first comma are the same.
2. Have program complete before our sun runs out of
   hydrogen, so that ruled out iterating every line through every line.

I then learned about (a,b) in zip but then i had a new problem. I want to merge the lines from the lists only when the first number in the lines are the same...and within the lists, some numbers are skipped in one list, duplicates, garbled trash once in a while, etc. so I can't just go line by line and can't figure out if there's a way to iterate through **only** a or b when using zip. I realize these are files that should be in a database and you query from there, but it's an exercise for me to learn more Python.

I'm using Python3.4 on windows. If anyone has suggestions on completing the following, or start from scratch, I would greatly appreciate it!

I want the lines with same usernumbers to be merged together in a new file. My current code follows:

```
list1 = open('bigfile1.txt', 'r', errors = 'ignore')    
list2 = open('bigfile2.txt', 'r', errors = 'ignore')

for a,b in zip(list1,list2):   

    c = (''.join(a.split("(")[1:])).rstrip()
    d = ''.join(c.split(",")[:1])

    e = (''.join(b.split("(")[1:])).rstrip()
    f = ''.join(e.split(",")[:1])

    if d == f:
        #FILE.write()
        print (a,b)

    elif d != f:
#####  I'm STUCK!!  #####

#FILE.close()
list1.close()
list2.close()
```

Comment: may I ask... why is there "random junk once in a while"? How do you identify it?  Usually just checking `if line.isspace()` is enough to skip over the unneeded lines in my files...

Comment: The data is from a large database..I discovered the corrupt data when in my original script, i converted the usernumbers to integers with z=int(f) and y=int(d) so I could try something like if z < y , etc. It ran for a while then threw an exception that it couldn't convert to integer. I located than line, and it was some continuation of a line or something...I copied and pasted the text in that line and made a " if "text from that line" in line" to skip that one and it ran ok for a while until it happened again. So  I need to be able to skip the junk lines and iterate over a and b individually

Comment: Also, i just edited my question above and changed the usernumbers in my example to reflect what is happening to me. So if my script skips the line with junk in it, from that point forward it will not merge lines anymore because    d != f

Answer (score 0):

Note: adding a wrapper to an iterator *will* reduce performance.  Sorry.

You can skip lines of the file by wrapping the file iterator, this just means writing your own generator with a conditional:

```
from itertools import chain

def ignore_junk(file_iter):
    for line in file_iter:
        if line[0] == "(" and line[1:3].isdigit():
            yield line


pair_rows_iter = zip(ignore_junk(list1),ignore_junk(list2))
all_lines_iter = itertools.chain.from_iterable(pair_rows_iter)
new_file.writerows(all_lines_iter)
```

Comment: Just from looking at that, it seems like I would have the same problem in that it would skip both lines in list1 and list2 simultaneously, so the usernumbers would never match up again?

Comment: it would not, if you can detect the junk lines it will skip those lines for both files independant of the other, the `ignore_junk` filter is applied to the file iterators not after they are `zip`ped together

Comment: Yes, it will skip the lines with junk, but it looks like it will pair the lines together if it begins with " ( " followed by numbers. I need to edit my question above to show the other issue.... as you can see now, in the data that I'm working with, in addition to junk lines, once in a while a usernumber is missing in one of the files. So i need to somehow compare if the usernumbers are the same. they start at 10 and go up to over 20 million.